# Displaying cache headers

Tags: php, symfony, header

Symfony 2 is displaying cache headers, i was wondering how i could hide those

examples

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Type: text/html Date: Fri, 18 Jan 2013 19:07:08 GMT HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Date: Fri, 18 Jan 2013 19:07:08 GMT X-Debug-Token: 50f99d5cba4da
```

i am using this in my code

```
return new Response($this->renderView('Shout/view/default.html.twig'));
```

which gets called by

```
$httpKernel = $this->container->get('http_kernel');
        $response = new Response;
        $response->SetContent($httpKernel->forward('MyBundle:Module/'.$module.'/'.$module.':index'));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        return $response;
```

in a twig extension

Comment: Why do you want to remove them? They are your friends :?

Comment: i don't want to remove them, i wan't them to not be shown on my page

Answer (score 6):

Add ->getContent() to end.

http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.html

```
    $response = $this->forward("MyBundle:Module:$module", array(
            'customer_id'  => $customer_id
    ))->getContent();

    return $response;
```

Comment: Thanks! Its work for me! It work for `$this->render()->getContent()` too.

Answer (score 2):

Headers are part of the [Response class](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.html) inside HttpFoundation. You can manage them using the headers attribute, the same one you used in your code. That attribute is an instance of the [ResponseHaderBag class](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ResponseHeaderBag.html), which has a remove function.

The header you want to remove is named 'Cache-Control', so if you write:

```
$response->headers->remove('Cache-Control');
```

It will remove that header. But if you check the source of Response, you will see that some of it's functionality depends on this header, so I'm not sure that removing this is really a good idea.

By default this header does nothing wrong, just returns 'no-cache', which means the browser won't cache your page. But you won't be able to cache a page without this header.

If your goal is to manually send the cache-control header yourself, consider using [Symfony2's built in functionality](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/http_cache.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

For everyone that is looking for an answer, i continued on the above post and tried to use the render function from twig but with my custom module

this is was i got and it works fine :)

```
return $this->container->get('templating.helper.actions')->render('MyBundle:Module/'.$module.'/'.$module.':index', $attributes, $options);
```